# I can't get my WebBrowser and Textbox to display when I execute the app. I can see them in my design window.

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, webbrowser-control

Here is my XAML and C# code along with it.  I'm pretty new to xaml so have some grace towards me.  Like I mentioned above I simply cant see the WebBrowser window or the TextBox when I execute the app.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="HTML_Viewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="HTML Viewer" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="grid_Main">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Open HTML File"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
            <Separator/>
            </MenuItem>
            <ToolBar Width="Auto">
                <Button x:Name="btnLocal" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Content="Load Local" Click="btnLocal_Click" Width="67" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                    Margin="0,0,0,-1" Height="22"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnCodeView" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Content="Code View" Click="btnCodeView_Click" Width="67" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,-1"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnPageView" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Content="Page View" Click="btnPageView_Click" Width="67" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,-1"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnSplitView" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Content="Split View" Click="btnSplitView_Click" Width="67" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,-1"/>
            </ToolBar>
        </Menu>

        <Grid Name="innerGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="col1" Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="col2" Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <WebBrowser x:Name="webOutput" Width="{Binding ElementName=col1,Path=ActualWidth}"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtInput"  Background="Bisque" Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding ElementName=col2,Path=ActualWidth}"
                 Height="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=ActualHeight}"     />
        </Grid>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

namespace HTML_Viewer
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCodeView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnLocal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
      {
        webOutput.Navigate(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));
        txtInput.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
      }
    }

    private void btnPageView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSplitView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to view your Controls by removing Height and width given to that,

```
 <WebBrowser x:Name="webOutput" />
 <TextBox x:Name="txtInput"  Background="Bisque" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: That solved it thanks.  I wonder why that was causing it?  I was doing the bindings so that the textbox and browser would adjust with the window re-sizing but it works anyway.